# Understanding of proof Ostrik Theorem 1

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation

I am currently reading the proof of Theorem 1 on page 1o in Victor Ostrik's Module categories (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139).

I don't understand why the functor he defines $N \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}(N, M)$ goes to $\mathcal{C}$ - why is $\mathrm{Hom}(N, M)$ part of $\mathcal{C}$?

Sorry if I am just blind... I'm thankful for any hint :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paper, the functor is *not* defined by $N\mapsto \operatorname{Hom}(N,M)$, it is actually defined by $N\mapsto \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(N,M)$. This bifunctor $\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}$ is an *internal* hom-functor, so it is an object of $\mathcal{C}$ (as in Definition 11).

Comment: Oh, you are right. Could you maybe explain why this functor $X \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}(X \otimes M_1, M_2)$ is in $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: @Polly $X\mapsto \operatorname{Hom}(X\otimes M_1,M_2)$ is not a functor $\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}$ either, it's a functor $\mathcal{C}\to \mathbf{Set}$ (or $\mathcal{C}\to \mathbf{Vect}_k$, since the categories considered are linear). It is **represented** by the internal hom, in the sense that $\operatorname{Hom}(X\otimes M_1,M_2)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(X,\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(M_1,M_2))$ naturally in $X$; for this to make sense you need $\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(M_1,M_2)$ to be in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still new to the whole subject "represented functors", so that's why I forgot about that. You can't by any chance explain to me, why this exact sequence in part 4) of the proof exists? That would be wonderful :D